# POST data in URL

Tags: php, html, post, get

In my page I have a table and I insert data into it from my DB with PHP. There are links in each row in the table. Each link directs the user to corresponding page. But these pages are like an exact copy of each other with just a small difference. A word.

Now that's stupid, to create bunch of pages for each link. Then change just a single word in them. Instead I want to create a single page. Post the data from the main page (in the url) and get the data (from url?) in the target page and do stuff. Well, I should just show do code:

```
<td class="align-left">
    <a href="artist.php?artist=<?php echo $row['Link'] ?>"><?php echo $row['Name'] ?></a>
</td>
```

This is the row I'm talking about. This loops through the DB and `$row['Link']` changes every iteration. Generated code would look like this:

```
<td class="align-left">
    <a href="artist.php?artist=3doorsdown">3 Doors Down</a>
</td>
```

`artist.php` page includes this code at the top:

```
<?php include('vars/3doorsdown.php'); ?>
```

This `3doorsdown.php` page includes some variables to be used in the page. What I want to do is get the `3doorsdown` from the url (`artist.php?artist=3doorsdown`) and put it in the target page. Like this:

```
<?php
    $postData = /*parse url and get data */;
    include('vars/' .$postData. '.php');
?>
```

I don't know how to post and get data from url in php. So I need few pointers.

Comment: `$postData = $_GET['artist'];`

Comment: Above comment is correct.  Be careful not to confuse GET and POST data.  GET data is visible in the URL and is appropriate when loading the web page will not modify anything.  POST data is generally for create/update/delete scenarios and is not sent in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your form on your webpage is using `method="get"`, then use `$_GET['variable']` to access the values of the querystring.

```
<?php
    $artist = $_GET['artist'];
    echo $artist;
?>
```

If you are using a `method="post"`, then you would be using `$_POST['artist'];`

Answer (score 0):

You can get that value from the `$_GET` array. Check if the file exists first, then include it.

```
$file = 'vars/' .$_GET['artist']. '.php';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    include $file;
}
```